# Group by clause - only first "group row" filled with values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Hy guys, i need your help !

Actually i have a select statement which contains a group by col1,col2,col3

[image]

But what i need is, that only the first row of the "group" should show the value. the following rows should be null or blank. It should look like this:

[image]

Is that possible!? and if yes, how? :-)

Thanks for your help!!
Anja

Comment: Please edit the question and post the sql you have tried.  Take a look at the oracle analytic functions.

Comment: Also, please provide you sample data as text, preferably SQL statements. People cannot cut'n'paste from images, which means they need to type out everything by hand, which is tedious and time-consuming. You are asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to help you: you are more likely to get a helpful response earlier if you make it easy for people to write and test code.

Comment: This sort of formatting is a matter for UI configuration rather than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually called a *break*. SQL*Plus has it, Oracle Reports does, Application Express as well ... so, depending on where you're going to use it, there's a possibility that you'll be able to do it declaratively, by choosing which columns you're going to break the report on.

This is a SQL*Plus example.

First, Scott's EMP table "as is":

```
SQL> select deptno, job, ename, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by deptno, job, ename;

    DEPTNO JOB       ENAME             SAL
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
        10 CLERK     MILLER           1300
        10 MANAGER   CLARK            2450
        10 PRESIDENT KING             5000
        20 ANALYST   FORD             3000
        20 ANALYST   SCOTT            3000
        20 CLERK     ADAMS            1100
        20 CLERK     SMITH             800
        20 MANAGER   JONES            2975
        30 CLERK     JAMES             950
        30 MANAGER   BLAKE            2850
        30 SALESMAN  ALLEN            1600
        30 SALESMAN  MARTIN           1250
        30 SALESMAN  TURNER           1500
        30 SALESMAN  WARD             1250

14 rows selected.
```

If you apply breaks, then it looks like this:

```
SQL> break on deptno on job
SQL> select deptno, job, ename, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by deptno, job, ename;

    DEPTNO JOB       ENAME             SAL
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
        10 CLERK     MILLER           1300
           MANAGER   CLARK            2450
           PRESIDENT KING             5000
        20 ANALYST   FORD             3000
                     SCOTT            3000
           CLERK     ADAMS            1100
                     SMITH             800
           MANAGER   JONES            2975
        30 CLERK     JAMES             950
           MANAGER   BLAKE            2850
           SALESMAN  ALLEN            1600
                     MARTIN           1250
                     TURNER           1500
                     WARD             1250

14 rows selected.
```

Pretty much as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use `first_value` function with `between 3 following and unbounded following` windowing clause :*

```
with t(col1,col2,col3,col4) as
(
 select 'A', 'A1', .3, 'Pramisse 1' from dual union all  
 select 'A', 'A1', .3, 'Pramisse 2' from dual union all    
 select 'A', 'A1', .3, 'Pramisse 3' from dual union all 
 select 'A', 'A1', .3, 'Pramisse 4' from dual union all     
 select 'A', 'A2',  1, 'Pramisse 1' from dual union all    
 select 'A', 'A2',  1, 'Pramisse 2' from dual union all 
 select 'A', 'A2',  1, 'Pramisse 3' from dual union all 
 select 'A', 'A2',  1, 'Pramisse 4' from dual union all     
 select 'A', 'A3',  1, 'Pramisse 1' from dual union all    
 select 'A', 'A3',  1, 'Pramisse 2' from dual union all 
 select 'A', 'A3',  1, 'Pramisse 3' from dual union all 
 select 'A', 'A3',  1, 'Pramisse 4' from dual   
)    
select first_value(col1) over 
         ( partition by col2 order by col4 rows 
           between 3 following and unbounded following ) as col1, 
       first_value(col2) over 
         ( partition by col2 order by col2 rows 
           between 3 following and unbounded following ) as col2, 
       first_value(col3) over 
         ( partition by col2 order by col4 rows 
           between 3 following and unbounded following ) as col3, 
       col4
  from t;

COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
----    ----    -----   ----------
A       A1      0,30    Pramisse 1
                        Pramisse 2
                        Pramisse 3
                        Pramisse 4
A       A2      1       Pramisse 1
                        Pramisse 2
                        Pramisse 3
                        Pramisse 4
A       A3      1       Pramisse 1
                        Pramisse 2
                        Pramisse 3
                        Pramisse 4
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/YZH73599)</kbd>